# How can I handle password input?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am managing user table by SonataAdminBundle

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper){ 
    $formMapper    
    ->with('General')   
     ->add('username')    
     ->add('email') 
     ->add('plainPassword','text',array('required' => false))
```

I leave password input blank,when I edit the existing user data.
It is OK,password is kept as same .

However I forgot to input password when I create new item.
It shows SQL error(password has required attribute in database)

but if I deleted required => false attribute,

```
->add('plainPassword','text')
```

it requires new input when you edit.

How can I change the behavior or How can I handle password
 input as normal input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use different field type for create and update actions. In your configure configureFormFields:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    // ...

    if ($isCreateAction) {
        $formMapper->add('plainPassword','text');
    }
    else {
        $formMapper->add('plainPassword','text', array('required' => false));
    }   
}
```

I don't know how to set `$isCreateAction` exactly, but maybe you could check `Admin::getSubject()` method? Inside it there is a routine to get GET id. If there is no id set, then action type is `create`.

Comment: Thanks !  I use '$this->getSubject()->getId()' it soloved my problem.